# Using Jquery queue to execute sequence of Ajax calls, need to clear queue if a request fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, queue

I'm trying to make a queue of ajax calls that will be executed in order. It seems to work ok, the problem is if there's an error in any of the calls, I want the queue to stop after the error so remaining ajax calls in the queue are not executed.

I'm kind of new to the idea of a jquery queue, i found this code online to extend jquery:

```
var ajaxQueue = $({});

(function($) {

    $.ajaxQueue = function(ajaxOpts) {

        // hold the original complete function
        var oldComplete = ajaxOpts.complete;

        // queue our ajax request
        ajaxQueue.queue(function(next) {    

            // create a complete callback to fire the next event in the queue
            ajaxOpts.complete = function() {
                // fire the original complete if it was there
                if (oldComplete) oldComplete.apply(this, arguments);    
                next(); // run the next query in the queue
            };

            // run the query
            $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
        });
    };

    // this is my addition, in an attempt to find ways to clear the queue
    $.clearQueue = function(ajaxQueue) {
        ajaxQueue.clearQueue();
        ajaxQueue.stop();
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Then i have this function to add an item to the queue

```
function queueAjax( passObj, success, ajaxQueue ) {

    $.ajaxQueue({
        url: route() + 'global_fxns/ajaxHub',
        async: true,
        data: {'passme' : encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( passObj ) ) },
        success: function(data) {

            var aJSON = decodeURIComponent(data);       
            var retObj = $.parseJSON(aJSON);    

            // if there was no problem, call the success function that was passed
            success( passObj, retObj );                    

        },
        error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            clog("error");

            // again this is my addition, trying to find ways to clear queue        
            ajaxQueue = $({});
            $.clearQueue(ajaxQueue);
        } 
    });
```

and finally to call queueAjax:

```
    var arr = standardAjaxArray( "testQueue", 0 );
    var obj1 = { 
        arr: arr,
        count: 1
    };
    function success( passObj, retObj, ajaxQueue ) {
        clog("Queue success!");
    }
    queueAjax( obj1, success );
```

The problem is no matter what i try i can't get the queue to empty if there's an error in the ajax call. I intentionally put an error in the ajax PHP side, then call queueAjax 4 times, and it runs 4 times every time. As you can see, i've tried extending jQuery with $.clearQueue, and i've also tried passing the queue as a parameter into the ajax function with no success. any input would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it, I was on the right track in the $.clearQueue definition i just removed ajaxQueue = $({}) before calling ajaxQueue.clearQueue() and it seems to work now. I think by using ajaxQueue = $({}), which was in itself an attempt to clear the queue, i was just reassigning the ajaxQueue variable and not emptying it, so when i subsequently called .clearQueue() there was no effect